# cuales serian los parámetros del form?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

les comento que ando aprendiendo a usar nodeJs y ando practicando con este repositorio [push-server](https://github.com/evansmusomi/push-server)
pero no logro dar con la manera de usar la posibilidad le enviar desde el form html , tengo entendido que esta entra por `const { url, method } = request;` pero no logro que se envie la notificacion push en mi navegador, gracias por sus ayudas.
Este podria ser el form pero no envia el mensaje para la notificacion

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:3333">
<input type="text" name="data">
<button type="submit">enviar</button>
```

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

// Get request vars
const { url, method } = request;

// Subscribe
if (method === "POST" && url.match(/^\/subscribe\/?/)) {
  let body = [];
  // Read body stream
  request.on("data", chunk => body.push(chunk)).on("end", () => {
    // Parse subscription body to object
    let subscription = JSON.parse(body.toString());

    // Store subscription for push notifications
    push.addSubscription(subscription);

    response.end("Subscribed");
  });

  // Public Key
} else if (url.match(/^\/key\/?/)) {
  response.end(push.getKey());

  // Push Notification
} else if (method === "POST" && url.match(/^\/push\/?/)) {
  let body = [];
  // Read body stream
  request.on("data", chunk => body.push(chunk)).on("end", () => {
    // Send notification with POST body
    push.send(body.toString());

    response.end("Push Sent");
  });

  // Not Found
} else {
  response.status = 404;
  response.end("Error: Unknown Request");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

si estas usando express por ejemplo al estar desestructurando la request como lo estas haciendo url y method no son propiedades dentro del objeto request, los que si son propiedades son header, body, param, hostname, etc
Osea si queres desestructurar la url y el metodo primero tenes que ver por cual de las anteriores lo estas enviando, si lo estas enviando por body seria algo asi

> const { url, method } = request.body

Comment: Hola Facundo, bienvenido y gracias por tu respuesta, mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada, de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: hola, gracias le intentare hacer haber que resultados obtengo, muy amable.